# How to increase number of characters in ASP.Net_SessionId cookie

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies

We had some penetration testing done on our websites recently and one of the issues that was found was that the ASP.Net_SessionId cookie contains a value 24 characters long, but we were recommended that it should be 64 characters. I understand that the cookie is generated by ASP.Net, but everything I've found online suggests that the length of the cookie cannot be changed. I don't understand why we would be told it's too short if that's the case? Can anyone shed some light on this? Our websites are built on .Net Framework 4.5.1, if that's useful.